# Tile GeoTIFF images in locations far from each other in one layer

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles, gdalbuildvrt

How to tile two aerial TIFF images from two cities in one layer?

I understand that first, I should create a virtual layer (vrt) and then tile it after reprojection. However, gdal2tile creates too many transparent tiles in the no data areas which are actually not needed. How to efficiently tile multiple GeoTIFF images which are far from each other in one layer?

Also, images are of EPSG:25832 and they need to be reprojected to EPSG:3857.

```bash
gdalbuildvrt -addalpha -hidenodata -srcnodata 0 -allow_projection_difference lindau_milbertshofen.vrt *.tif

gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 lindau_milbertshofen.vrt lindau_milbertshofen_nodata.vrt

gdalwarp -of GTiff -r cubic -s_srs EPSG:25832 -t_srs epsg:3857 -co "tfw=yes" --config CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE NO lindau_milbertshofen_nodata.vrt lindau_milbertshofen_nodata_25832_3857.vrt

gdal2tiles.py -z 1-22 --resampling=cubic --processes=30 --srcnodata=0 lindau_milbertshofen_25832_3857.vit  lindau_milbertshofen
```

Comment: [`-x` Exclude transparent tiles from result tileset](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#cmdoption-gdal2tiles-x) Also don't `gdal_translate`, just `gdalwarp` and output another VRT instead of a GeoTIFF.